# How to solve ClassCastException?

Tags: android

```
public void showDateTimeFrameDialog(){
    Calendar now = Calendar.getInstance();
    com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker.date.DatePickerDialog dpd = com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.newInstance(PaymentHistoryFragment.this,now.get(Calendar.YEAR),now.get(Calendar.MONTH),now.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
    dpd.show(getActivity().getFragmentManager(), "Datepickerdialog");
}
```

I am using two different DatePickerDialog libraries those are

https://github.com/wdullaer/MaterialDateTimePicker and   https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker as dependencies in my app     and when I click on the   com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker.date.DatePickerDialog. Its showing Below Exception.

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException:com.wdullaer.materialdatetimepicker.date.AccessibleDateAnimator cannot be cast to com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker.date.AccessibleDateAnimator 
                      at   com.borax12.materialdaterangepicker.date.DatePickerDialog.onCreateView(DatePickerDialog.java:371)
                      at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2069)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:899)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1072)
                      at android.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:851)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1478)
                      at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:452)
                      at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5537)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
                      at  com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
```

Comment: please edit your question with code block which gives error too

Comment: Ok ..now you can check

Comment: This is a known issue. Haven't got any solution https://github.com/borax12/MaterialDateRangePicker/issues/45